# Upload File to rest wep api c#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello i try to send Image to Web api from my xamarin-forms app and save it in my database but i have problem with convert to base 64
i Used plugin to pick image and i try to convert it to Image base 64 and it didnt give me corect string image base 64

```
    _aktFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (_aktFile == null)
                return;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    ImageStream = _aktFile.GetStream();
                    ImageMessageByteArray = new byte[_ImageStream.Length];
                    ImageStream.Read(_ImageMessageByteArray, 0, (int)_ImageStream.Length);
                    ImageMessageBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(_ImageMessageByteArray);
                    return _aktFile.GetStream();
                    
                });
```

Comment: "didnt give me corect string" - how do you determine it's not correct?

Comment: and how can i use it and how i should do it?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and doesn't really add any useful information to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
_aktFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

if (_aktFile == null)
 return;
else
{
 string Base64String = ConvertStreamToBase64(_aktFile);
}

private string ConvertStreamToBase64(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                base64selectedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            return base64selectedImage;
        }
```